# I'm getting the following errors when I try to drop or delete a database table

Tags: jdbc, netbeans, javadb

I'm getting the following errors when I try to delete a table. Does the table include the mismatched data type for Image?

> Unable to execute command:
>   drop table "APP"."GADGET"
>   DDL is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database.

Comment: Let recheck your user's role is granted to delete this table. I think your user account is not permited to delete

Comment: i'am unable to delete , edit and update any data into it , it says "Unable to execute command: drop table "APP"."GADGET" DDL is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database."

Comment: Please provide the code that is used to create the `Connection`.

Comment: Are you using Apache DB? I have no experience on it, but I think you can try to relogin with admin user, then, run grant statement to your current user.

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html

Comment: No , iam using JDBC:derby let me try

Comment: Connection.setReadOnly(boolean ) is used to set a connection to either read-only ( select queries ) or write mode (DDL, DML).